# regular expression question

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace the question mark (?) in a string with some other words. What is the regular expression for question mark.
For example, I want to replace question mark in "word=?" to something else, say "stackoverflow". Then the result would be "word=stackoverflow".
What is the syntax in java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
string.replaceFirst("\\?", yourWord)
```

That will replace the first occurrence of a `'?'` in your code with whatever `yourWord` is.

If you want to replace every `'?'` with `yourWord` then use `string.replaceAll("\\?", yourWord)`.

See the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for more info.

Comment: To avoid confusion about (Java) strings and immutability, I always try to phrase answers like this as assignment expressions:  
`str = str.replaceFirst("\\?", yourWord);`

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, you can take the "magic" out of magic characters such as "`?`", "`*`", "`.`" and so forth, by using the escape character, which is a backslash ("`\`").

The tricky part is that in Java, in a string, the backslash is ALREADY used as an escape, so to construct a Java String whose value is "`\?`", you have to code it as "`\\?`" so as to escape the escape character.